# Use all 24 Gb for one application on the K80 GPU

Tags: keras, pytorch

The [Tesla K80](https://technical.city/en/video/Tesla-K80)  has 24 Gb but, as far as I understand, it is [shared between two GK210 GPUs](https://www.tomshardware.com/news/nvidia-gk210-tesla-k80,28086.html) on the same card. So actually it's a card with two 12 Gb GPUs.
But is it still possible to use all 24 Gb for one application fx training a large model in PyTorch or Keras?

Comment: There is nothing automatic which can make that happen. You would require the framework your are using to internally implement a multi-gpu scheme. That has nothing to do with CUDA per-se.

Comment: Normally you have two copies of the same ML model with different batches of data for each GPU.

Comment: There are approaches for splitting the model into parts. But those approaches would also work with one GPU doing one part after the other. Theoretically it should be possible to use unified memory or let the GPUs cooperate, but in practice the data exchange probably is just too slow.